# Java. Как создать лобби/сервер, чтобы туда зашли люди и взаимодействовали с кнопкой

Tags: java

Нужно сделать, можно сказать игру. Есть кнопка и несколько команд, нужно узнать, кто первый, кто второй и т.д до последнего нажал на кнопку. Меня интересует как сделать лобби, чтобы туда могли зайти люди и могли взаимодействовать с этой кнопкой. Можно ли обойтись без сервера, может есть какой-нибудь простенький способ?

Comment: Самый простенький вариант это  консольные приложение на сокетах, вместо кнопки можно просто выводить контекстное меню с командами. Либо изучите java FX и там кнопку сделайте.

Comment: Без сервера не обойтись , как вы себе это представляете.  В качестве сервера может выступать простая программа на java с сервер сокетом который будет прослушивать порт и ждать подключения. Но чтоб к вам подключились вам нужен выделенный IP

Comment: Если прям в режиме онлайн это делать , то нужно подождать пока 3 человека/сокета подключаться, пришлёт подтверждение о готовности, запустить обратный отчёт и там уже смотреть какой из сокет в потоках первый записался в переменную  ,базу ну или что-то типа такого   . Если делать это через сайт , то через один сервлет впринцепе можно наверно это сделать, хотя тут уже ajax нужен будет , чтобы оповещать Браузеры о готовности и т.п. . Ну вот через консольныое приложение помойму самый быстрый варик

Comment: большое спасибо!